# Set hook exception programmatically

Tags: php, prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.7

In a custom module for prestashop, how would one define a hook exception for a special page (front controller) of the own custom module?

I know that i can register for hooks in the `install()` method of the module by e.g. `$this->registerHook('displayHome')` and hooks can be configured in the prestashop admin panel under `improve -> design -> positions` (and there also under `transplant a module`). This works for all hooks for which the `public function hookDisplayX($params)` method is implemented.

When transplanting a module, it is possible to define exceptions for pages where the hook of the module is not executed. This results in a DB entry in the table `PREFIX_hook_module_exceptions` with the modules filename (format `module-<modulename>-<controllername>`), some module ID and some hook ID.

The question is now, how would i define this exception e.g. during the `install()` method (or possibly later). The only information i have is the exception filename (since i know which controller is responsible for showing the content).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code:

```
$this->registerExceptions(
    Hook::getIdByName('hookNameHere'),
    array(
        'attachment',
        'contact',
        'other-page-name',
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, too bad i didnt find that in the documentation anywhere :/